# A sql query to create multiple rows in different tables using inserted id

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to insert a row into one table and use this row's id to insert two more rows into a different table within one transaction. I've tried this

```
begin;
insert into table default values returning table.id as C;
insert into table1(table1_id, column1) values (C, 1);
insert into table1(table1_id, column1) values (C, 2);
commit;
```

But it doesn't work. How can I fix it?

updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a CTE, and you don't need a begin/commit to do it in one transaction:

```
WITH inserted AS (
    INSERT INTO ... RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO other_table (id)
SELECT id
FROM inserted;
```

Edit:
To insert two rows into a single table using that id, you could do that two ways:

- two separate INSERT statements, one in the CTE and one in the "main" part
- a single INSERT which joins on a list of values; a row will be inserted for each of those values.

With these tables as the setup:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t1 (id INTEGER);
CREATE TEMP TABLE t2 (id INTEGER, t TEXT);
```

Method 1:

```
WITH inserted1 AS (
        INSERT INTO t1
        SELECT 9
        RETURNING id
), inserted2 AS (
        INSERT INTO t2
        SELECT id, 'some val'
        FROM inserted1
        RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO t2
SELECT id, 'other val'
FROM inserted1
```

Method 2:

```
WITH inserted AS (
        INSERT INTO t1
        SELECT 4
        RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO t2
SELECT id, v
FROM inserted
CROSS JOIN (
        VALUES
        ('val1'),
        ('val2')
) vals(v)
```

If you run either, then check t2, you'll see it will contain the expected values.

Comment: Thanks. It works, but what if I need to add values to other columns and be able to insert multiple rows like this?
I've updated my question to clarify

Comment: @Chickenfresh Updated my answer

Comment: Sorry, but why do you have 3 temp tables? I have only 2 tables and need to insert at least two rows with a couple values into table_2 using id of inserted row into first table_1

Comment: @Chickenfresh Updated

Comment: Is that Okay that in pgadmin it fails with error ```ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
SQL state: 25P02```?

Comment: It's not ok, but unlikely to have anything to do with this query (which I can guarantee is 100% valid as I ran it on my machine). I use pgadmin 3, presumably you use 4, and I don't know how that one works. If you're doing that following on from your original code, try executing `rollback` then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below query:

> insert into table1(columnName)values('stack2');
>
> insert into table_2 values(SCOPE_IDENTITY(),'val1','val2');